# java mail Store.connect hangs - doesn't timeout

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail

I'm using plain old java mail (mail-1.4.1.jar - JVM 1.6.0_03-b05) to connect to an IMAP store:

```
Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(new Properties(), null);
Store store = mailSession.getStore("imap");
store.connect(host, user, pwd); // Hangs here
folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
...
```

Problem is, occasionally the thread hands at `store.connect` and never returns.

```
"MyThread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0a9c3000 nid=0x2095 runnable [0x9ccd3000..0x9ccd4130]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:110)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
        - locked <0xc09003e8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at com.sun.mail.iap.ResponseInputStream.readResponse(ResponseInputStream.java:97)
        at com.sun.mail.iap.Response.<init>(Response.java:96)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.<init>(IMAPResponse.java:61)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPResponse.readResponse(IMAPResponse.java:135)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.readResponse(IMAPProtocol.java:261)
        at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:114)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:104)
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:538)
        - locked <0xc04c73d0> (a com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
        - locked <0xc04c73d0> (a com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
        at package.MyClass.checkInbox(MyClass.java:116)
```

There is no mention of timeout settings in the [javamail spec](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/JavaMail-1.2.pdf) and I cannot find any suitable 'setter' methods on either `Session` or `Store`.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: What timeout param did you set to fix your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the javadocs for the [com.sun.mail.imap package](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html) for the properties you can set to control (among other things) timeouts.  Oh, and you probably want to upgrade to the latest version of JavaMail.